# how to backup my android phone data on my PC

Tags: android

I want to Backup all my Android Phone data on my Personal computer.I am going to update my Android Device, but for new device i want to import previous device's data.

Comment: my advice: go to superuser. You will get down voted like hell for this question here. Life is tough sometimes ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use Mobogenie Software for doing the job for Backingup all your Android Phones data on your Personal Computer.

Answer (score -1):

Try helium titanium and other backup applications.